# MySQL - Query most recent input based on username - VERY SLOW

Tags: php, mysql, indexing

I have a table being constantly inserted to with various usernames.  I have a page a user can load which shows the most recent entry in the database that was posted by them.

An example of the query I'm using: SELECT timestamp FROM entry_list WHERE username='user' ORDER BY entry_id DESC LIMIT 1

There is a 2-column index in the table:  username, timestamp .  This index is being used according to the EXPLAIN query, with the following additional information:

select_type: SIMPLE
type: ref
key_len:  34
ref:  const
rows:  5654
Extra: Using where; Using index; Using filesort

How can I optimize my query?  It's fairly fast for a single user (0.2~0.4 sec), but some accounts load this information for 5, 10, or even 20 different users at once.  Even 0.2~0.4 seems a bit long, and when it ends up slowing page load down by 4-8 seconds, it's unacceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM entry_list WHERE username = 'user'`

also, probably not the best idea to use reserved keywords as column names, try changing `timestamp` to `insert_date` or something like that

Comment: Thank you!  This change made it load a user with 20 accounts being tracked in less than 0.01 seconds!

Answer (score 0):

You could add a field to the user table `last_query_id`. Then just update this field when you they make a new query. `last_query_id` should point to an index in the table you're currently searching (from what I can tell.) This approach avoids searching through tons of records to find the most recent one.